# Does GRE Tunneling support the Websocket Protocol?

Tags: tunneling

Just curious because I am going to use a GRE Tunnel that has a ddos filtered ip, then tunnel it to my main gameserver. My gameserver uses HTML 5 Websockets and port 9300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRE is a tunneling protocol at the network layer (OSI layer 3) and thus will transport everything above it, which includes TCP (layer 4) and HTTP (layer 7). And since WebSockets are just some kind of tunnel inside HTTP it will transport them too.

Comment: WebSocket is not *under HTTP*, because of HTTP limitation WebSocket is a *sibling* protocole, linked to HTTP for javascript applications. So WebSocket is a *TCP* protocol, as you rightly said: *which is, like everything, transported by GRE.*

Comment: @F.Hauri: WebSockets are established by using the Upgrade facility of a HTTP request. Thus WebSockets are essential a layer 4 protocol like Tcp inside a Tunnel created by a layer 7 protocol (HTTP). There are no WebSockets without HTTP first.